# Stopping own process

Tags: c, linux

The concerned code is very huge and hence i am sorry i cannot post it here. The issue is:- I wrote a small program as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
int main()
{
printf("\n Process id",getpid());
fflush(stdout);
if(kill(getpid(),SIGSTOP)!=0)
    printf("\nError");
}
```

Upon running i get the following o/p:

Process id 2664

[1]+ stopped ./test_SIGSTOP

[Directory Path]$

Which is exactly what is expected. But in my actual program which i said is very huge...control comes to just above the kill call(I know it as I have print statements and fflushed them) and hangs without automatically stopping the process and appearence of the command prompt. 
Would be gratefull for pointers.
Thank

Comment: Mind posting at least the function in which `kill` is called, just for some context?

Comment: Does this larger program have any sort of signal handler mechanism which might be catching SIGSTOP?

Comment: I could suppose that your process did fork and one of the parent or child still running. And, I'd like to note that SIGSTOP cannot be caught.

Comment: Why don't you use `exit()` instead of `kill`?

Comment: Have you spawned off any processes?  If so you may have just created a zombie process.

Comment: Yes SIGSTOP,SIGCONT and SIGKILL cannot be caught. I have not spawned off any processes BUT I do have its parent still running. Probaby that is the issue.

Comment: @zvrba thanks! didn't know that :)
not sure why my comment got so many up-votes :S

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a debugger to a running program and find out where/why it hangs.  Also, the `raise()` function is more convenient to use. But first, use ps and inspect the process's flags to confirm its status (running / sleeping / stopped).